# Why I obtain this HibernateException related to a named query in this Spring project?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

I am absolutly new in Hibernate and Spring development and I have the following problem

I have this entity class named KM_ProjectInfoStatus that map a DB table named KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS, so I have this class:

```
package egp.prc.km.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusList", query = "select status from KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status order by status.idProjectInfoStatus") ,
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusById", query = "SELECT status FROM KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId")
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS")
public class KM_ProjectInfoStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idProjectInfoStatus;

    @Column(name = "foldertech")
    private Long foldertech;

    @Column(name = "folderproject")
    private Long folderproject;

    public Long getIdProjectInfoStatus() {
        return idProjectInfoStatus;
    }

    public void setIdProjectInfoStatus(Long idProjectInfoStatus) {
        this.idProjectInfoStatus = idProjectInfoStatus;
    }

    public Long getFoldertech() {
        return foldertech;
    }

    public void setFoldertech(Long foldertech) {
        this.foldertech = foldertech;
    }

    public Long getFolderproject() {
        return folderproject;
    }

    public void setFolderproject(Long folderproject) {
        this.folderproject = folderproject;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the previous snippet, uppon the class are definied 2 **named queries**, these:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusList", query = "select status from KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status order by status.idProjectInfoStatus") ,
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusById", query = "SELECT status FROM KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId")
})
```

1) The first one is named **kmProjectInfoStatusList** and select a list of rows from my **KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS** table.

2) The second one is named **kmProjectInfoStatusById** and select a single row from my **KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS** table using the id in the where condition.

Then I have to implement a Spring service that realize a DAO.

So I first create an interface named as **KMProjectInfoStatusService** in which I declare the method of my DAO:

```
public interface KMProjectInfoStatusService {

    @Transactional
    public List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus> getProjectInfoStatusList();

    @Transactional
    public KM_ProjectInfoStatus getProjectInfoStatus(Long idProjectInfoStatus);
}
```

I am absolutly new in Hibernate and Spring development and I have the following problem

I have this entity class named KM_ProjectInfoStatus that map a DB table named KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS, so I have this class:

```
package egp.prc.km.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusList", query = "select status from KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status order by status.name") ,
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusById", query = "SELECT status  FROM KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status  where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId")
})

@Entity
@Table(name = "KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS")
public class KM_ProjectInfoStatus implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long idProjectInfoStatus;

    @Column(name = "foldertech")
    private Long foldertech;

    @Column(name = "folderproject")
    private Long folderproject;

    public Long getIdProjectInfoStatus() {
        return idProjectInfoStatus;
    }

    public void setIdProjectInfoStatus(Long idProjectInfoStatus) {
        this.idProjectInfoStatus = idProjectInfoStatus;
    }

    public Long getFoldertech() {
        return foldertech;
    }

    public void setFoldertech(Long foldertech) {
        this.foldertech = foldertech;
    }

    public Long getFolderproject() {
        return folderproject;
    }

    public void setFolderproject(Long folderproject) {
        this.folderproject = folderproject;
    }
}
```

As you can see in the previous snippet, the class contains also 2 named queries, these:

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusList", query = "select status from KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status order by status.name") ,
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusById", query = "SELECT status  FROM KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status  where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId")
})
```

Then I have to implement a Spring service that realize a DAO.

So I first create an interface named as KMProjectInfoStatusService in which I declare the method of my DAO:

public interface KMProjectInfoStatusService {

```
@Transactional
public List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus> getProjectInfoStatusList();

@Transactional
public KM_ProjectInfoStatus getProjectInfoStatus(Long idProjectInfoStatus);
```

}

Finally I create the **KMProjectInfoStatusServiceImp** class that implement the previous interface and that represent my concrete DAO:

```
@Repository("kmProjectInfoStatusService")
public class KMProjectInfoStatusServiceImpl extends AbstractService implements KMProjectInfoStatusService {

    public List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus> getProjectInfoStatusList() {
        //return new KM_ProjectInfoStatus[0];  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

        return getHibernateTemplate().execute(
                new HibernateCallback<List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus>>() {
                    public List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                        return getStatusList(session);
                    }
                }
        );
    }


    public KM_ProjectInfoStatus getProjectInfoStatus(Long idProjectInfoStatus) {
        //return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.

        final Long id = idProjectInfoStatus;
        return getHibernateTemplate().execute(
                new HibernateCallback<KM_ProjectInfoStatus>() {
                    public KM_ProjectInfoStatus doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
                        return getStatus(id, session);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    private List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus> getStatusList(Session session) {
        //create query:
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("kmProjectInfoStatusList");
        List<KM_ProjectInfoStatus> statusList =  query.list();

        return statusList;
    }

    private KM_ProjectInfoStatus getStatus(Long idProjectInfoStatus, Session session) {
        //create query:
        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("kmProjectInfoStatusById");
        query.setParameter("statusId", idProjectInfoStatus);

        KM_ProjectInfoStatus status = (KM_ProjectInfoStatus) query.uniqueResult();

        return status;
    }
}
```

As you can see in this class I implement the 2 methods **getProjectInfoStatusList()** and **getProjectInfoStatus()** declared in the interface. These 2 methods use respectivelly the **getStatusList()** to perform the first named query to obtain the list and **getStatus()** that perform the second query to obtain an object from its id.

The problem is that when I try to execute my project an **HibernateException** is throwns and I obtain the following error message in the stacktrace:

```
2014-12-29 16:25:44,210 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(363) - Error in named query: kmProjectInfoStatusById
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS is not mapped [SELECT status  FROM KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status  where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.requireClassPersister(SessionFactoryHelper.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromElementFactory.addFromElement(FromElementFactory.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.FromClause.addFromElement(FromClause.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:255)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3056)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2945)
    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
    ................................................................................
<29-dic-2014 16.25.44 CET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149202> <Encountered an exception while attempting to commit the 1 task for the application 'KM_Web_war_exploded'.> 
<29-dic-2014 16.25.44 CET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application 'KM_Web_war_exploded'.> 
<29-dic-2014 16.25.44 CET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: :org.hibernate.HibernateException:Errors in named queries: kmProjectInfoStatusById, kmProjectInfoStatusList
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:365)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Why? What could be the problem? What am I missing? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: as it's says: `KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS is not mapped`

Comment: It is HQL not SQL you must use....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your in the Hibernate world, so you need to use Hibernate entity names and no longer SQL table names. By default, an entity name is the simple name of a class.

So you should write instead something like:

```
select status from KM_ProjectInfoStatus status order by status.name
```

Google more info on HQL/JPQL for the details.

Answer (score 1):

**HQL needs classname and SQL needs table name**

use `KM_ProjectInfoStatus` in your HQL instead of `KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS`.

```
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusList", query = "select status from KM_ProjectInfoStatus status order by status.name") ,
        @NamedQuery(name = "kmProjectInfoStatusById", query = "SELECT status  FROM KM_ProjectInfoStatus status  where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId")
})
```

**HQL** `thus should not use table names, but entity class names`

Answer (score 1):

This is supposed to be HQL query (not SQL):

```
SELECT status FROM KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS status where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId
```

So you shouldn't use the table name (`KM_PROJECT_INFO_STATUS`) but rather the entity class name (`KM_ProjectInfoStatus`) like this:

```
SELECT status FROM KM_ProjectInfoStatus status where lower(status.idProjectInfoStatus) = :statusId
```

Here is a [link to Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html#ql-from-clause) related to the HQL FROM clause.

Also please try following standard Java naming conventions. It will make your code more readable :)